# OpenGL screen coordinates

Tags: opengl, vertex-shader

I can successfully manipulate 3d objects on the screen in openGL.

To add a 2d effect, I thought I could simply turn off the matrix multiplication in the vertex shader (or give the identity matrix) and then the "Vertices" I provide would be screen coordinates.

But 2 simple triangles refuse to display (a square 0,0,100,100, tried various depths, but this same code works fine if I give it a rotating matrix.

Any ideas?

```
  static const char gVertexShader[] = 
  "attribute vec3 coord3d;\n"
  "uniform mat4 mvp;\n"
  "void main() {\n"
  "gl_Position = mvp*vec4(coord3d,1.0);\n"
  "}\n";
```

->

```
  static const char gVertexShader[] = 
  "attribute vec3 coord3d;\n"
  "uniform mat4 mvp;\n"
  "void main() {\n"
  "gl_Position = vec4(coord3d,1.0);\n"
  "}\n";
```

EDIT:  I was unable to get anything to show using the identity matrix as a transformation, but I was able to do so using this one:

```
  glm::mat4 view = glm::lookAt(glm::vec3(0.0, 0.0, -5), glm::vec3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0), glm::vec3(0.0, 1.0, 0.0));
  glm::mat4 pers = glm::perspective(.78f, 1.0f*screenWidth/screenHeight, 0.1f, 10.0f);
  xform = pers * view * glm::mat4(1.0f);
```

You'd have to adjust the -5 to fully fill the screen...

Comment: If you want to draw something in 2D it is often useful to use an orthographic projection instead on a perspective projection.

Answer (score 3):

The `gl_Position` output of the vertex shader does expect `clip space` coordinates, not window space. The clip space coords will be forst transformed to normaliced device space and finally be converted to window space coords using the viewport transform.

If you want to directly work with window space coodrs for your vertices, you can simple use the inverse of the viewport transform as the projection matrix (the clip space will be identical to normalized device space when you work with orthogonal projections, so you don't need to care about that).

In NDC, (-1, -1) is the bottom left corener and (1,1) the top right one, so it is quite easy to see that all you need is a scale and a translation, you don't even need a full-blown matrix for that, these transforms will nicely end up as multiply-add operations GPUs can handle very efficiently.

Comment: I can use any coord system that works.  so to confirm if I use clip space -1,-1 to 1,1 it should work?  what is NDC?  I am using opengl es (phone)

Comment: @AndrewStone: what exactly did you try what didn't work. Using (-1,-1,z,1) (with z in [-1,1]) as clip space coord will be mapped to the bottom left corner (actually, the outer corner of the _pixel_, not just the center of the corner pixel) of the viewport you selected.

Comment: I tried this.  I don't think I am changing internal GL settings for projection matrix,etc.  I put all my matrix xforms into that single matrix multiply (now removed).GLfloat testSFVertices[] = 
{
-1.0, -1.0, 0.0,
0.0, -1.0, 0.0,
0.0, 1.0, 0.0,
-1.0, 0.0, 0.0,
};

Comment: @AndrewStone: it is unclear what is actually happening in your code, but the transforms are as I described them.

Comment: I was unable to get it to display using the identity matrix, but was able to do so using this matrix:{{{  glm::mat4 view = glm::lookAt(glm::vec3(0.0, 0.0, -5), glm::vec3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0), glm::vec3(0.0, 1.0, 0.0));
  glm::mat4 pers = glm::perspective(.78f, 1.0f*screenWidth/screenHeight, 0.1f, 10.0f);
  xform = pers * view * glm::mat4(1.0f);
}}}

Comment: @AndrewStone: as I already said: it is impossible to figure out what is going on without seeing the relevant parts of the code.